# Detect when Meteor Cordova App goes into Background

Tags: cordova, meteor

How can you detect when the Meteor.js Cordova app goes into the background? I found that Cordova has a [`pause`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0rc1/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause) and `resume` function, how do you access it from Meteor?

```
document.addEventListener("pause", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

The package provided by FBA shows (and I did just test it) that you can actually just use the same syntax you've already provided:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", function() {
    Session.set('cordovaStatus', 'paused')
    Meteor.disconnect()
});
```

Here's how the package uses it: [cordova-status.js](https://github.com/AdamBrodzinski/Meteor-Cordova-Status/blob/master/cordova-status.js)

Answer (score 1):

Its not a native feature of Meteor. So you would need to add a cordova package or you can use this one created for meteor.

https://github.com/AdamBrodzinski/Meteor-Cordova-Status